# Android. Deeplink not working with standard launch mode

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack, android-deep-link, launchmode

I have main (launcher activity) with singleTask launch mode (e.g. A). I need this launch mode to handle deeplink. But when I fo from my main activity to another activity B and press to home button, when I launch my app is opening activity A, but expected B. How to solve this problem. With standard launch mode activity stack is preserved but deeplink not working.

Comment: Please explain why the deeplink does not work with standard launch mode. Explain what happens in this case. Also, please edit your question and post your manifest.

Comment: Instead of responding to my question, you just posted another question which is just as confusing as this one. Please provide more exact details of your problem if you wish to get an answer.